# Why My Hi-Tech Chemical Compound Lost Its Full Effectiveness?

Tags: cleaning

I have bought this thing a month ago:

[image]

[image]

It is so far best dust cleaner that I have ever used and all was well until I left it out of its package for half day. Then it became sturdy and could be torn apart, less sticky and flexible which I **[video'ed here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=899m6yaII_E&hd=1)**.

Can this item be restored back to fully functioning state as it was before? Maybe it just became dry and I should put it in a place with moisture?

Since all was in Chinese, I also do not know the storage conditions that must be met.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use something similar called cyberclean. You ABSOLUTELY need to keep it in a airtight container

from the cyberclean website

> Yes. Cyber Clean® may become dry if not stored in the resealable containers it comes in. >Please note that dry Cyber Clean® cannot be re-used and you should replace it with a new >Cyber Clean®. We recommend keeping the packaging Cyber Clean® comes with to store it >properly and seal after use so you can use it again and it won´t dry up.

Considering that ziplock bags can be iffy, i'd suggest replacing it and storing it in a airtight screwtop or clicky container in future.

Comment: Thank you Journeyman Geek. Can i use food plastic storage containers or even glass containers which might be better but less convenient?

Comment: as long as its airtight.

Comment: jars that seal work well too...